# Where do computed styles for width and height come from when they aren't listed in my css

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

Obviously I can open display and it will tell me exactly where these are listed, but where do the fields with no arrow (in this case height and width) come from? afaik these values are not listed anywhere in my css. Is this clientWidth and clientHeight?

[image]

Comment: These are computed styles by the browser.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements-styles

Comment: Each node has it own CSS properties. they get applied if you does not override them

Answer (score 2):

The default value of `width` for a block element like a `div` or a `p` is `auto` in CSS 2.1 (nope, it isn't 100%)

Thus what you see is (*veeeery roughly speaking*) the **width of the parent** (taking into account borders, padding, margin, `box-sizing` and so on).
There are many other cases explained in CSS 2.1 REC **[Visual formatting model details](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html)**

Comment: +1 definitely my guess. I thought it would be 'auto' as well, but in this case it seems to be the width of the parent as you mention. I'll look through the REC to see how it applies.

Answer (score -1):

Those are computed styles generated by chrome for whatever element you're inspecting. How it's actually generated might be JavaScript based or it could be something different. It's nothing to worry about though. It's the same thing as your OS telling you the size of an image or a file.

Comment: no offense, I'm really wondering specifically where the values come from, i already know what they are, just need to know exactly why width = 'n' when i didn't specify 'n' :)